# O(n^2) (or O(n^2lg(n)) ?)algorithm to calculate the longest common subsequence (LCS) of two 'ring' string

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a problem appeared in today's Pacific NW Region Programming Contest during which no one solved it. It is problem B and the complete problem set is here: http://www.acmicpc-pacnw.org/icpc-statements-2011.zip. There is a well-known O(n^2) algorithm for LCS of two strings using Dynamic Programming. But when these strings are extended to rings I have no idea...

P.S. note that it is subsequence rather than substring, so the elements do not need to be adjacent to each other

P.S. It might not be O(n^2) but O(n^2lgn) or something that can give the result in 5 seconds on a common computer.

Comment: Are you sure an O(n^2) algorithm exists?  They say the "large" cases are only 1500 letters.  1500^3 is only around 3.3 billion, which should not take too long on a fast machine...  But then O(n^3) is kind of trivial

Comment: @Nemo Well I am sure that a O(n^3) algorithm won't do, because the time limit is 5 seconds. It could be O(n^2log(n)) or something else though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching the web, this appears to be covered by section 4.3 of the paper "Incremental String Comparison", by Landau, Myers, and Schmidt at cost O(ne) < O(n^2), where I think e is the edit distance. This paper also references a previous paper by Maes giving cost O(mn log m) with more general edit costs - "On a cyclic string to string correcting problem". Expecting a contestant to reproduce either of these papers seems pretty demanding to me - but as far as I can see the question does ask for the longest common subsequence on cyclic strings.

Comment: Thank you! (Well I see that this is indeed a hard problem and I spent much time on it during the contest..)

Answer (score 1):

You can double the first and second string and then use the ordinary method, and later wrap the positions around.

Comment: I tried that at first, but then if the raw strings overlap then when you double them this LCS will be doubled too. And it may become complicated.... I also tried to calc the LCS of one string and the double of another, but it has similar problem

Comment: @dementrock: I don't understand, can you show sample strings?

Comment: For example (as in the problem), "megamind" and "mindmega", when you simply double it you will get "megamindmegamind" and "mindmegamindmega" in which case the length of the LCS is l2! ("megamindmega") (I did not calculate it carefully but it's still a counterexample)

Comment: For the method I tried, take "metrocity" and "kryptonite" (I forgot to mention the string could also be reverted but that doesn't matter so much to the algorithm). Doubling one of them, say "metrocity" and "etinotpyrketinotpyrk", in which case the length of LCS is greater than or equal to 6 ("etroty") but the original LCS is "etoty"

Comment: @Nemo: how? ABAB doesn't show up in the doubled first string, "ABCDEABCDE"

Comment: Sorry I should have made another clarification: for the LCS problem here the characters in substring does not need to be adjacent

Comment: OK let me try again...  ABCD vs. BACD.  Your algorithm gives ABCD (or BACD).  But neither of those is correct; all correct answers only have three letters.  (ABCD doubled is ABCDABCD. BACD doubled is BACDBACD.  Both have ABCD as a subsequence.  Note subSEQUENCE, not subSTRING.)

Comment: @Nemo: he said 'ring' strings, which by the definition of ring I know doesn't have a start or an end; 'ABCD' = 'BCDA', which have a common subsequence of the whole string.

Comment: I did not say ABCD vs BCDA.  I  said ABCD vs BACD.  They are not rotations of each other, but your algorithm thinks they are.  That is kind of my whole point.

Comment: @Dani Again it is a subsequence rather than a substring. So it's B[A]CD[B]A[CD]

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to "double" the strings and apply the standard dynamic programing algorithm. The problem with it is that to get the optimal cyclic LCS one then has to "start the algorithm from multiple initial conditions". Just one initial condition (e.g. setting all Lij variables to 0 at the boundaries) will not do in general. In practice it turns out that the number of initial states that are needed are O(N) in number (they span a diagonal), so one gets back to an O(N^3) algorithm.
However, the approach does has some virtue as it can be used to design efficient O(N^2) heuristics (not exact but near exact) for CLCS.

I do not know if a true O(N^2) exist, and would be very interested if someone knows one.
The CLCS problem has quite interesting properties of "periodicity": the length of a CLCS of
p-times reapeated strings is p times the CLCS of the strings. This can be proved by adopting a geometric view off the problem.

Also, there are some additional benefits of the problem: it can be shown that if Lc(N) denotes the averaged value of the CLCS length of two random strings of length N, then
|Lc(N)-CN| is O(\sqrt{N}) where C is Chvatal-Sankoff's constant. For the averaged length L(N) of the standard LCS, the only rate result of which I know says that |L(N)-CN| is O(sqrt(Nlog N)). There could be a nice way to compare Lc(N) with L(N) but I don't know it.

Another question: it is clear that the CLCS length is not superadditive contrary to the LCS length. By this I mean it is not true that CLCS(X1X2,Y1Y2) is always greater than CLCS(X1,Y1)+CLCS(X2,Y2) (it is very easy to find counter examples with a computer). 
But it seems possible that the averaged length Lc(N) is superadditive (Lc(N1+N2) greater than Lc(N1)+Lc(N2)) - though if there is a proof I don't know it.
One modest interest in this question is that the values Lc(N)/N for the first few values of N would then provide good bounds to the Chvatal-Sankoff constant (much better than L(N)/N).

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to mcdowella's answer, I'd like to point out that the O(n^2 lg n) solution presented in Maes' paper is the intended solution to the contest problem (check http://www.acmicpc-pacnw.org/ProblemSet/2011/solutions.zip).  The O(ne) solution in Landau et al's paper does NOT apply to this problem, as that paper is targeted at edit distance, not LCS.  In particular, the solution to cyclic edit distance only applies if the edit operations (add, delete, replace) all have unit (1, 1, 1) cost.  LCS, on the other hand, is equivalent to edit distances with (add, delete, replace) costs (1, 1, 2).  These are not equivalent to each other; for example, consider the input strings "ABC" and "CXY" (for the acyclic case; you can construct cyclic counterexamples similarly).  The LCS of the two strings is "C", but the minimum unit-cost edit is to replace each character in turn.

At 110 lines but no complex data structures, Maes' solution falls towards the upper end of what is reasonable to implement in a contest setting.  Even if Landau et al's solution could be adapted to handle cyclic LCS, the complexity of the data structure makes it infeasible in a contest setting.

Last but not least, I'd like to point out that an O(n^2) solution DOES exist for CLCS, described here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0396 At 60 lines, no complex data structures, and only 2 arrays, this solution is quite reasonable to implement in a contest setting.  Arriving at the solution might be a different matter, though.